# Getting tag from fragment on onTimeSet

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I have an MainActivity which handles fragments. On one of the fragments I do:

```
enterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePickerExit");

        }
    });

    exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePickerEnter");

        }
    });
```

And on my MainActivity I get the result:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
```

with the function:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

//Who called it?
}
```

How can I know at onTimeSet who called it enterBtn or exitBtn?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541258/android-timepickerdialog-timepickerdialog-ontimesetlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a boolean flag for enter and exit button.

```
isExit = false;
enterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        isExit = false;
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePickerExit");

    }
});

exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        isExit = true;
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePickerEnter");

    }
});
```

and in the Override method

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    if(isExit)
    {
        // Do your task here if Exit button click
    }
     else
    {
        // Do your task here if Enter button click
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution but it will do. Thought more like use tags or something...

Comment: Yes I know that, and I have facing this issue for years but there is no solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do some thing like

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("btnNumber", 1); //or 0
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePickerExit");
```

and then in fragment make your on `interface`

```
private OnCompleteListener mListener;
/// your otherDialogStuff

public static interface OnCompleteListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(Int fragNumber, int hourOfDay, int minute);
}



// make sure the Activity implemented it
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener)activity;
    }
    catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
    }
}
```

and then `onTimeSet` call

```
 mListener.onComplete(0or1 ,12,12);
```

and your activity should implement `TimePickerFragment.OnCompleteListener`